# ValueError: x and y must be the same size. Scatterplot Issue

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am attempting to make plots using appended data, and compare it's values from year to year.

Here is the code for the appendage

```
HFCTOTAL=np.append(HFC_152a,HFC_134a)
HFCALL=np.append(HFCTOTAL,HFC_365)
```

When I do `HFCALL.shape` I get a matrix value of `(9429,)`

When I do this shape value for my time function of years, from 2009-2019, I get a matrix value of `(3143,)`

While attempting to plot any values here, the error output is as follows

```
plt.scatter(Year,HFCALL)
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error message points really to what is wrong. Try to do a plot by hand with x and y axis with the following data:
x1=2; x2=3; x3=4 and y1=1; y2=2.

Comment: You could create the scatterplot as `plt.scatter([Year, Year, Year], [HFC_152a, HFC_134a, HFC_365], s=1)`. That way both x and y are of dimension 3x3143